# Fancytree ajax loading issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancytree

When running the following jsp code, all I get is "loading..." and nothing happens.
This is my first time using ajax with [Fancytree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree).
I tried a number of variations, even adding the ajax commented-out line, but no luck.
I am using jquery-1.9.1 and Fancytree 2.0.

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  ...
  //ajax: { type: "POST", contentType: "application/json" },
  source: {
    url: "getTreeData.jsp",
    cache: false
  },
  ...
});
```

The output from getTreeData.jsp

```
[{title: 'First', key: '153', folder: false, id: '4', content: 'ABCDEFG'}]
```

Comment: Are you returning `Content-type: application/json` as a http header of getTreeData.jsp? What about if you set that array directly on the source property, does it work then?

Comment: Does your getTreeData.jsp have a `parent` parameter and does it allow HttpGet?

Comment: That output is not a valid JSON (if the response from getTreeData.jsp is exactly like you put in the question). Needs double colon on keys and values that are string: `[{"title":"First","key":"153","folder":false,"id":4,"content":"ABCDEFG"}]`

Comment: One of the things i tried was p pasted the jsp output directly into the source, so I think the json string is ok.

Comment: I tried using double quotes around strings -- and it worked!!!  Thank you all.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL could you post this as answer, so Dave can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

That output is not a valid JSON (if the response from getTreeData.jsp is exactly like you put in the question).

Needs double colon on keys and values that are string, like the following:

```
[{"title":"First","key":"153","folder":false,"id":4,"content":"ABCDEFG"}]
```